# Can Sphinx Section Numbering Skip Certain Sections (like a title)?

Tags: python-sphinx, sections, toctree

I am making a series of design documents in Sphinx and I would like to include them together in a `toctree` and have the sections within the documents numbered. I know that I can use `.. sectnum::` to number all sections in the child pages. However, Sphinx/rst numbers the title of the page (which is really just the first section) and the table of contents ends up looking like:

```
Table of Contents
    1 Design the First
    2 Design the Second
```

and each child page looks like:

```
1 Design the First
1.1 First Section
1.2 Second Section
```

What I want is a table of contents on my index page that just lists the title

```
Table of Contents
    Design The First
    Design the Second
```

and child page that look like

```
Design the First
1 First Section
2 Second Section
```

Is there a way to have a title that shows up in the TOC as well as on the top of a child page which does not end up being a numbered section?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you ended up doing, but I wanted to do the exact same thing!  I had the following setup:

```
index.rst

.. toctree::

   assignment
   library_api
```

I only wanted the assignment part to have numbers, so either could have done two separate `toctree` with one using `:numbered:`, or put at the top of the file

```
.. sectnum::
   :start: 0
```

Giving of course the exact problem you mention -- my top-level title was `Assignment Writeup`, so that was `0` and everything below it in subsections was `0.x`  e.g.

```
Assignment Writeup
==================

First Task
----------

Second Task
-----------
```

gives

```
0. Assignment Writeup
    0.1 First Task
    0.2 Second Task
```

as it turns out, there's an easy hack you can do.  It makes things more modular than probably desired, but "add a layer of indirection".

So now I have `assignment.rst` and `assignment_writeup.rst`.  `assignment.rst`  just basically has a title and a `toctree`:

```
Assignment Writeup
==================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   assignment_writeup
```

then take all sub-sections and put them in `assignment_writeup` and "upcast" their heading level.  So I now take all subsections and make them sections, and subsub and make them sub.

```
.. sectnum::
   :start: 0

First Task
==========

^^^ === instead of --- now

Second Task
===========
```

and we now finally have

```
Assignment Writeup
    0. First Task
    1. Second Task
```

kind of dubious, but this was the only way I could achieve it x0  I wonder what you did between asking this and now?  Hopefully somebody will see this and benefit one day!

**Note**: this has undesireable side-effects.  The Assignment Writeup shows up on its own page, with just Links to the indirect document.  Not sure which is worse honestly...

Comment: Five years later and no solution?